# Use React.forwardRef in Typescript with no props

Tags: reactjs, typescript, eslint, tslint

I'm trying to forward a ref to a Typescript component that does not take any props. When I use `React.forwardRef` it takes two parameters: props and ref. My component does not use props. How can I declare my component with no linting or compilation errors?

Right now I have:

```
// this says "props is declared but its value is never used"
const MyComponent = React.forwardRef((props = {}, ref: Ref<HTMLDivElement>): JSX.Element => {
  return (
      <div ref={ref}>
        Fun stuff
      </div>
  );
});
```

If I declare an empty interface for my props like this:

```
interface myProps {}
```

Then I get `An empty interface is equivalent to '{}'` but then when I try to declare with just `{}` and no actual interface then I get:

```
Don't use `{}` as a type. `{}` actually means "any non-nullish value".
- If you want a type meaning "any object", you probably want `Record<string, unknown>` instead.
- If you want a type meaning "any value", you probably want `unknown` instead.
```

Is there some way that I can declare an interface/type for these props which expects an empty object and doesn't cause me linting issues?

Update: When I use an empty object type as recommended from this issue thread, it causes a type error where the component is used.

```
Type '{ ref: RefObject<HTMLDivElement>; }' is not assignable to type 'Pick<NoElements<Record<string, never>>, string>'.
  Property 'ref' is incompatible with index signature.
    Type 'RefObject<HTMLDivElement>' is not assignable to type 'never'.
```

Shows at:

```
<MyComponent ref={refToForward} />
```

Seems like there's a chicken egg situation.

Comment: what if you used `React.forwardRef<HTMLDivElement, any>()` instead?

Answer (score 5):

If you want to use `forwardRef` but don't need props, you can try this:

```
const MyComponent = forwardRef((_: unknown, ref: Ref<HTMLDivElement>) => {
  return (
      <div ref={ref}>
        ...
      </div>
  );
});
```

Comment: Changing from `_props: undefined` to `_props: unknown` fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

You could prefix the `props` with an underscore like this `_props` to get rid of `props is declared but its value is never used`.

And for the empty interfaces I usually use types, so, in your case, that would be `type myProps = {}`.

UPD:

How about we pass the types into the `<>`, like:

```
type Props = {};

const MyComponent = React.forwardRef<HTMLDivElement, Props>((props, ref) => {
  return (
      <div ref={ref}>
        Fun stuff
      </div>
  );
});
```

Comment: Using a type still gives me an error:
Don't use `{}` as a type. `{}` actually means "any non-nullish value".
- If you want a type meaning "any object", you probably want `Record<string, unknown>` instead.
- If you want a type meaning "any value", you probably want `unknown` instead.

Comment: Ok, so I looked into it and it appears you're using `typescript-eslint` config.

Basically, what are you trying to do is not encouraged in the comments of the repo, but you could always `// eslint-disable-next-line` to get rid of the messages or reconfigure your `.eslintrc` file:
`{
  "rules": {
    "@typescript-eslint/ban-types": [
      "error",
      {
        "extendDefaults": true,
        "types": {
          "{}": false
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}`

Comment: `Basically, what are you trying to do is not encouraged in the comments of the repo`. What exactly isn't encouraged? Do you have a link? Is an alternative suggested somewhere?

Comment: Sure, here it is https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/issues/2063#issuecomment-632833366 look at the last section of the comment by bradzacher and let me know if it means something else, cause I would want to know too :)

Comment: I guess the recommended way would be to define props of the component, but since you want to omit them it's better to either reconfigure the eslint or disable that particular rule on that particular line

Comment: That issue you referenced is VERY helpful. I think the preferred solution here would be to use one of the empty object types that are listed there. I need to play with it a bit more to see which would work best then I'll let you know and you can edit this answer.

Comment: Hmm, adding the empty object type gives me an error where the component is used. I feel like I'm going in circles here. See the updated question.

Comment: I think you might want to change the approach of defining the types of `forwardRef`, so check out the upd in the answer

Answer (score 0):

For me, it worked with an underscore after using `ref` due to this lint rule `after-used` argument at https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/no-unused-vars#args-after-used which roughly states that the previous param will not be checked if the next one is used. I know it's a little late question but hope this answer helps someone though.